# GitHub Pages: Is it possible to map multiple sub-domains to the same repository?

Tags: github, subdomain, github-pages

In my `urig.github.io` GitHub Pages repository I have setup:

1. A simple index.html homepage in the root folder `/`.
2. A Jekyll generated blog in the `/blog` folder.

Is it possible to map my custom sub-domain `www.urig.io` to point to the homepage at `/` and at the same time map `blog.urig.io` to the `/blog` folder? If so, how can I do it?

Comment: [This](https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/about-custom-domains-and-github-pages) may help.

Comment: Thanks @GoodDeeds. That is a useful link. However, I do not see an explanation on how to setup a custom sub-domain to point to a folder like `/blog`. Any other ideas?